# Unknown Sources Check over Web Site?

Tags: javascript, android

The Android SDK has a way to check for "Unknown Sources using the following API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS"

However, I was wondering if there is anyway to use this through a browser or have Javascript do this?

There's a chicken and egg problem that I'm trying to understand of knowing if a user can install and unsigned app before they try to install an unsigned app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I was wondering if there is anyway to use this through a browser or have Javascript do this?

Not from a regular Web browser, sorry.